# Installing sqlite shell on Linux

Tags: linux, sqlite

I need to use a recent version of the sqlite shell to convert a .csv file to a sqlite database file (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69546483/create-sqlite-db-from-csv-file-using-php)). My hosting service uses Cloudlinux 7.9 which only includes the 3.17 version of sqlite, which isn't new enough for the functions I need.

I *thought* I could download the latest linux version of sqlite3 (a flat file), ftp it to my working folder, then use that version.  But, when I enter

```
./sqlite3 --version
```

I get

```
bash: ./sqlite3: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030306/lib-ld-linux-so-2-bad-elf-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory) seems to be pertinent, but what's a good next step here given that I have very limited access to the remote, hosted system?

Edit 10/14/2021 --

So I need the 32-bit libraries.  I'v posted a ticket with the hosting service.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer per se, but my provider will not install new binaries on a shared system, so I'm pursuing an alternate solution.